# I can not open the url of the site deployed with dokku

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment, backend, dokku

Hello everybody) I started learning dokku. Going through the tutorial from the documentation for the Heroku Ruby on Rails "Getting Started" app I can't go to url generated by dokku in the browser. I am only using my local machine while learning and doing git push to localhost. This command works without errors, the container works, I get the url to the site, but I cannot open it in the browser. The same problem appears with another project, when I try to deploy a python django project, this is just a project skeleton created by django, without my code. It must show a welcome page and I want to see it when the site is running on dokku but I cannot go to the url. I tried to use dokku domains and dokku proxy but couldn't solve the problem. Please help me figure out how to fix this. I'm new to dokku, docker, nginx and deployment so the problem can be trivial. I'm also want to know on which ip, port dokku runs the sites and on which ip do I need to run the wsgi server inside the container?

Comment: You can run your site inside the container on any port, the dockerfile needs to use the expose keyword to expose that port though, Dokku will run on the host IP, usually when you have no domain set for the dokku app it will throw a URL like `myapp.localhost.guest`, this wouldnt work on localhost so you'd probably want to go to either localhost:dockerport or if you've proxied your app to port 80, then just localhost, without knowing the URL its giving you, its hard to tell whats going wrong

Comment: @dune184 Hi thanks for responding. Ok, `localhost:80` opens sites. Yes, dokku gave me the default url `http://ruby-getting-started.evgenycomp`, but why doesn't it work on the local machine and what do I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: the url that dokku gives isnt a real url, its just a reference to the local machine, what do you see when you go to localhost:80? is it blank, is it a 502 error? without knowing that its also hard to tell